# Sending Emails to thousands of users at once in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am running a website in Laravel 5.3.*. I developed it by myself. I am using contact form and inquiry form for users to send me feedback. now I am thinking to add subscribe now for latest news function on my website.  Where I will get user email in a single input form and will store it in database table named subscribers. Now I am using standard `Mail` class for my contact form and inquiry form. What will be the correct and accurate method to send emails to thousands of users from database.

Comment: if the site is yours and you have access to server, like alternative you can set up some cron file that will run on specific time or repeat every X time and check if you have done some changes send email to all users in seconds. this will help in future when will be more people editing it, you will not need to track it by your self.

Comment: Sending out mass mailings can be problematic. If a small number of your the users see your emails as unwanted, your mail server might get banned. This can become a huge problem, basically all your emails will be rejected or delivered unreliably. I assume you've, at least, set up SPF and DKIM on your server? I always use an external services for sending out mass mailings.

Comment: An external service is mailgun for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel queues, it will be easy
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail